# Sencha touch check box issue on Iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm having an odd error in my sencha app that only appears on iphone.

[image: iPhone checkbox issue]

The checkbox does not apply itself to the full box, and only the white part is clickable. I can't seem to find anyone who is having this same issue, so i can only assume there is something wrong with the code i have written.

```
                {
                xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                name: 'tos',
                label: 'I accept the terms of service & privacy policy*',
                id:'tos',
                checked: false,
                listeners: {
                    check: function() {
                        $(this.fieldEl.dom).attr('value' , 'checked');
                    },
                    uncheck: function(){
                        $(this.fieldEl.dom).attr('value' , '');                             
                    }
                }
            },
```

Please let me know if you see anything that may be causing this problem.

Comment: How about the relevant markup and CSS? Also maybe try document.getElementById('tos').checked = true; to see if the attr call is not working. What does console.log(this.FieldEl.dom) output?

Comment: I know that the listeners are working because other parts of the cide rely on that attribute.

Comment: I just verified that the same issue is occurring on Safari, so hopefully that will allow me some insight into how to fix this

Comment: Are you using the latest official version, SenchaTouch 1.1.1?

Comment: Am also facing this issue but am facing issue only in iphone simulator. in web browser, android and blackberry simulator's its working fine. Actually am getting that space beside the check mark not on the check mark. :(

Comment: The solution to thias far as i could tell was to apply a set height to the input container. When i applies a CSS style {height:300px;} to that specific input it fixed the issue. Not entirely clean, and it makes that form field look weird. but it works?